# C# ASP.NET MVC: Single-Line If Clause in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got a trivial issue.. and can't solve it.

I have this in my view:

```
<% if (!Model.DisplayText) { %> <%= Model.MyText %> <% } %>
```

As you can see, i am using **3x** <% and %>. That just screams like bad code. But I can't seem to get this working in a single line. This throws all kinds of weird errors (such as semicolon missing, and when I add one it throws something else):

```
<% if (!Model.DisplayText) { Model.MyText } %>
```

Any idea?!

Comment: one of them actually writes to view content... that's your problem.

Comment: Just a note, the reason you're running into a no semicolon issue is because unlike "<%" which is for inline code, the "<%=" is for output and likely is transformed into a method call (something like page.write(Model.MyText);) when the page is parsed.

Comment: Your original code was fine.  There is nothing inherently wrong with 3x <% %>'s.  Just aim for clarity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= Model.DisplayText ? "" : Model.MyText %>
```

or

```
<% if(!Model.DisplayText) Response.Write(Model.MyText); %>
```

Comment: Beaten to the punch, nice post.

Comment: The ternary operator solution was exactly what I needed. Thank you! 

P.S. In that case there wouldn't be a semicolon so you may want to remove that for others that look up this solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
 <%= foo %>
```

is generally equivalent to:

```
 <% Response.Write(foo) %>
```

So you can write:

```
 <% if (!Model.DisplayText) { Response.Write(Model.MyText); } %>
```

but I don't see what you really get from this. Your original code is fine as it is. Or you might use the ternary operator, as OrbMan suggests.

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after the call to Response.Write at the least, and this is probably a case where the brackets would best be left out.

Answer (score 1):

is basically like writing Response.Write(your data)

 means the code will execute, but it's not going to specifically write anything out.

You could use a Response.Write inside your if block to output the data you want.

Or go with OrbMan's answer, he beat me to it.

Comment: All answers were great :) Thank you!